# value should is not a member of String - Scala2.10

Tags: scala, gradle, scala-2.10

I want to cross compile my project across different Scala versions (2.10, 2.11, 2.12). I get this error message while compiling specs for 2.10 only. 2.11 and 2.12 work fine:

> value should is not a member of String

Spec class looks as follows:

```
class ClassNameSpec extends WordSpec with Matchers {
  // ...
}
```

I have also tried changing `WordSpec` to `FlatSpec` and still getting same error.

Using gradle - `build.gradle` has following related dependencies:

```
classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.github.maiflai:gradle-scalatest:0.19'

compile "org.scala-lang:scala-library:${scalaVersion}"

compile "org.scalactic:scalactic${scalaVersionSuffix}:3.0.5"

testRuntime 'org.pegdown:pegdown:1.4.2'
```

How can I make `WordSpec` or `FlatSpec` with `Matchers` work for Scala2.10? If not, what's the best work around?

Comment: please post your code